# How can `SquareWave` be used as the input in `OutputResponse`?

Tags: functions, warning-messages

I'd like to compute the response of a `TransferFunctionModel` when driven by a `SquareWave`. Here's a simple example,

```
or = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 1), s], SquareWave[t], t];
```

which results in two copies of the error:

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>

Oddly, `or` still gets set to

```
{(-1 + Piecewise[{{-E^t, Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, Mod[t, 1], Less, 1]}}, E^t])/E^t}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

and is the correct response of the system to `UnitStep[t]`, but multiplied by `SquareWave[t]`.

How can `OutputResponse` be used to find the response of a `TransferFunctionModel` driven by a `SquareWave`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right about using finite sequence of pulses. But here is how you can get it still using `SquareWave` - you just need to introduce right cut-off. Then no sums over steps or pulses are needed and implementation is easy.

For example:

```
finiteSquareWave[t_] := UnitBox[.2 (t - 3)] SquareWave[t];
Plot[finiteSquareWave[t], {t, -2, 8}, Exclusions -> None,  Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

```
f[t_, z_] = OutputResponse[ TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 1), s], finiteSquareWave[t], t]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[f[t, z], {z, 0, 1.2}, {t, 0, 8}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Z", "T", "f(Z,T)"}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3]]
```

[image]

This is similar to what you got with sums over `UnitSteps`.

Comment: I like this one. When I attempt to change the phase of the `SquareWave` using `finiteSquareWave[t_] := UnitBox[.2 (t - 3)] SquareWave[t - 0.1];`, the error returns. Any idea why?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens it is not an error, but just a message that solution is given not in an exact, but numerical form. Plotting function and other computations still work.

Comment: 3D plot looks pretty :-), but it's only a cylindrical function, so what's the third dimension for?

Comment: @stevenvh f(z,t) - so 3 axis are z,t,f . It is a standard plot http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7kxbwzgfy-zycipu

Answer (score 4):

I hardly ever try to obtain an analytic expression from `OutputResponse` since I am really only interested in a plot of the response and an `InterpolationFunction`. So unless you have a need to see an analytical expression, use a numerical one. This happens when you provide a complete time specification as in `{t,0,10}` instead of just `t`.

Now you will obtain an `InterpolationFunction` which is for all practical purposes just as good. Not only is it **faster**, you know it will almost always work for any input.

```
In[3]:= or=OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(s+1),s],SquareWave[t],{t,0,10}]    
Out[3]= {InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]}
```

But if you insist you want an analytical response, then may be there is a way. But see first if the above works for you.

```
Plot[or, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A fake, finite-time version of `SquareWave` can be made thus:

```
sw = With[
 {period = 2},
 Sum[
  UnitStep[t - period/2 number] - UnitStep[t - period/2 (number + 1)],
  {number, 0, 10, 2}
 ]
]
```

And this fake `SquareWave` works with `OutputResponse`:

```
or = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 1), s], sw, t];
Plot[or, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]